# UITableView / UISearchBar Returns Incorrect Results

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ios-4.2

I am attempting to implement searching in a UITableView.  When searching, it appears that the correct number of results are returned, but I am receiving entries from the original stories array in the results, rather than searchResults.  I can see that the searchResults array should be the data source, but haven't been able to figure out after tons of searching quite how to pull it off with an array of NSDictionaries.  Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {
[self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

if ([self searchResults] == nil)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self setSearchResults:array];
    [array release], array = nil;
}

[[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];    

if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
{

    for (NSDictionary *currentItem in [self stories])
    {
        if ([[currentItem objectForKey:@"title"] rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [[self searchResults] addObject:currentItem];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NSPredicate for filtering

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.title MATCHES %@",searchTerm];
```

Suppose that your original array is "originalArray" so to get the filtered array use this make two more global variables

```
 NSArray* filteredArray;
 BOOL isFiltering;
```

Now in search bar delegate method do following

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
      NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.title MATCHES %@",searchTerm];
      filteredArray = [[originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] retain];
}
```

Now you need to change  l'll bit  your table view delegate and data source, .... for all the places where you are using

```
NSDictionary *currentString = [originalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

use following

```
NSDictionary *currentString;
if(isFiltering)
      currentString = [originalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
      currentString = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]` is also another alternative to making and managing your own `BOOL isFiltering;` variable